# Operador LIKE en campos CHAR con espacios a la derecha en Oracle 12cR2

Tags: sql-server, oracle-12c

Me encuentro trabajando con Oracle 12cR2 y con SQL Server 2014, realizando unas pruebas encontré ciertas diferencias con el operador LIKE en ambos gestores, las consultas que me dan resultados distintos son las siguientes, los campos son de tipo char con una longitud de 40, en Oracle la colección de caracteres que utilizo a nivel columna es BINARY, NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI, NLS_SORT=LINGUISTIC y NLS_CHARACTERSET=WE8MSWIN1252, en SQL Server a nivel base de datos la colección de caracteres es Latin1_General_CI_AS y a nivel columna es Latin1_General_BIN:

SQL Server:

```
SELECT NOMBRE FROM PERSONAS WHERE NOMBRE LIKE 'JOSE'; Resultado: JOSE
SELECT NOMBRE FROM PERSONAS WHERE NOMBRE LIKE '%OSE'; Resultado: JOSE
```

Oracle:

```
SELECT NOMBRE FROM PERSONAS WHERE NOMBRE LIKE 'JOSE'; Resultado: Ninguna fila ha sido seleccionada
SELECT NOMBRE FROM PERSONAS WHERE NOMBRE LIKE '%OSE'; Resultado: Ninguna fila ha sido seleccionada
```

Mi pregunta es, ¿existe alguna configuración que se deba de realizar en Oracle para evitar que tome en cuenta los espacios a la derecha? de antemano muchas gracias

Comment: No conozco si existe alguna configuración, pero, ¿es válido modificar la consulta así. `SELECT NOMBRE FROM PERSONAS WHERE TRIM(NOMBRE) LIKE '%OSE';`?

Comment: Las columnas tipo `CHAR` tienen longitud fija y eventualmente se completan con espacios, las columnas tipo `VARCHAR` son las que tienen una longitud variable (hasta un máximo) y obviamente no completan con espacios. Creo que problema viene por ese lado, en un servidor trabjas con VARCHAR y en otro con CHAR.

Comment: Mauricio no me es valido modificar la consulta y Patricio en ambos gestores estoy utilizando char

Comment: Si en ambos servidores usas char, el que está funcionando de manera incorrecta es SQL Server, pues no debiera devolver ninguna coincidencia también, ya que no puede haber una columna con valor `'JOSE'`, sino que siempre tiene que tener 40 caracteres de longitud, es decir, la columna tendría que tener de valor `'JOSE                                     '`